# what Linux distro should i get for old laptop

Tags: hardware

its a windows xp for now so any how to tell how to do it in xp
my old laptop:
 
Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1.40 GHz and 224 MB of RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the specifications- Will you still be running XP as well?  Although all Linux OS can run pretty smoothly on old devices, Lubuntu is probably the easiest to use (it resembles XP in my opinion), has all the features we know and love and is not resource hungry.

However if you're after more features and applications whatnot, I would suggest giving Ubuntu a go, and wiping everything! I mean, it is all trial and error, if you're going to wipe XP you can try any distro! I would recommend Lubuntu, Kubuntu and Ubuntu. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to your machine specifications I'd go with Lubuntu. It'd be wise to increase RAM as much as possible.